# Replace BLANKS with 0 using DAX in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have written the following DAX Query

```
Global Spends = CALCULATE(SUM(PSL[Total Spend]),FILTER(PSL,PSL[PSL Flag] = "Global"))
```

In some combinations of `Global Lead` and `Class` the `Global Spends` value is `BLANK` which means that there is no PSL Flag as `GLOBAL` for that combination.
I wanted to replace these blanks with 0 and I wrote this for it :

```
Global Spends = IF(ISBLANK(CALCULATE(SUM(PSL[Total Spend]),FILTER(PSL,PSL[PSL Flag] = "Global"))),0,CALCULATE(SUM(PSL[Total Spend]),FILTER(PSL,PSL[PSL Flag] = "Global"))
```

The following measure works with 0 errors but my table in power BI gives me more extra rows for all the combinations where Global Spends are 0 and hence disturbing the whole table.

How Do I replace blanks with 0's?

Sample Table

```
Global Lead | Class |Global Spends | Local Spends | Total Spends 
Marie | Software | 3M | 5M | 8M
Leela | Hardware |  | 2M | 2M
```

Here I want the blank to replace with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular visual:

```
Global Spends :=
IF ( 
    SUM ( PSL[Total Spend] ) > 0 ,
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( PSL[Total Spend] ) ,
        PSL[PSL Flag] = "Global"
    ) + 0 
)
```

Comment: Sorry - forgot to add the zero, which was the whole point!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
Global Spends = 
var ct = COUNT('PSL'[Lead]) 
return IF(ct > 0, CALCULATE([Total Spends], KEEPFILTERS('PSL'[PSL Flag] = "Global")) +0, BLANK())
```